# get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) is blank when logged in as "subscriber"

Tags: customization

Trying to create a delete link on frontend, but when logged in as a subscriber the `get_delete_post_link( $post->ID )` variable is blank. Link is fine when logged in as administrator.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be that the subscriber cannot delete posts. Try the below to find out.

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_post', $post->ID ) )
{
   echo 'I do not have the privilege to delete posts';
}
else{
     get_delete_post_link( $post->ID );
}
```

The above might lead you into trouble by letting any user delete any other users post so the below is aimed at letting only the post owner with a subscriber level delete their post or someone with the correct privilege.

```
          if ( get_the_author_meta('ID') == get_current_user_id() && current_user_can('subscriber') )
          {
            // owner of post and subscriber
            get_delete_post_link( $post->ID );
          }
          if ( get_the_author_meta('ID') != get_current_user_id()  && current_user_can('subscriber')  )
          {
            // not the owner of post and subscriber
            echo 'Not your post';
          }
          else
          {
           // should be ok as not a subscriber and has delete privilages
           get_delete_post_link( $post->ID );
          }
```

Comment: Ya, that is echoing true. We already have a user role plugin installed integrated with an upload form so not sure I can use another one on top of that to modify the subscriber permissions. Thoughts?

Comment: Google User Role Editor that plugin will let you edit any user role to be able to delete posts and will work with your current plugin. Please mark the question as correct as the answer is right. Thanks